# White tiles with Google Chrome and OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, css

I created personal tiles on my webserver, which works with Apache.
These tiles are in folders from 0 to 16 in Jpg format.
I render these local tiles with OL3.15.1.
On Firefox, IE Edge and IE10 I've no problem in loading these tiles, but with Google Chrome i see blank tiles.

This is an example of the rendering.
The white tile what you see appear few seconds ago.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find ! The problem was the "rendering hardware-accelerated" parameter. If I disable this option it's work !

But How with OSM tiles all it's good and with my personal tiles, it's not good ?